# Overcome MemoryError in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, out-of-memory

I have a huge data frame:

```
df.shape = (106, 3364)
```

And when I want to run the following code i get **MemoryError**

```
i = df.values.T
j = np.nansum((i - i[:, None]) ** 2, axis=2) ** .5
```

> MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 j = np.nansum((i - i[:, None]) ** 2, axis=2) ** .5
>
> MemoryError:

Any method to avoid that?

Comment: I guess axis should be 0 (columns) or 1 (rows). axis=2 doesn't make sense and probably will make a full copy of array

Comment: How important is that you use exactly `np.nansum`? If you are okay with just replacing nan values with zeros in the original array, you can use [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html).

Comment: (otherwise you can use Numba to compute this quickly just by looping)

Comment: @jdehesa No, in my case it is impossible to fill NaN with 0. Can you explain numba a bit more please?

Comment: @Marat Still getting Memory Error even with axis 0 or 1

Comment: @Marat, `axis` must be 2 for that calculation to make sense.  `i` has shape (3364, 106). `i[:, None]` has shape (3364, 1, 106), so with broadcasting `i - i[:,None]` has shape (3364, 3364, 106).  The squared values are summed along the last axis (`axis=2`) and then the square root is taken, so the result has shape (3364, 3364).  It is the array of all the pairwise Euclidean distances between the rows of `i`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thank you, I didn't see it

Comment: @Mamed, how much memory do you have?  That code will generate two intermediate results with shape (3364, 3364, 106), and if the values in these arrays are 64 bit floating point, each of those intermediate arrays requires over 9 gigabytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use Numba. It will consume less memory and actually be faster too.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

def compute_distances(df):
    i = df.values.T
    result = np.empty((len(i), len(i)), dtype=i.dtype)
    _compute_distances_nb(i, result)
    return result

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def _compute_distances_nb(data, result):
    for i in nb.prange(data.shape[0]):
        for j in nb.prange(data.shape[0]):
            s = 0
            for k in nb.prange(data.shape[1]):
                d = data[i, k] - data[j, k]
                if not np.isnan(d):
                    s += np.square(d)
            result[i, j] = np.sqrt(s)

# Original method for comparison
def compute_distances_np(df):
    i = df.values.T
    return np.nansum((i - i[:, None]) ** 2, axis=2) ** .5

# Test
np.random.seed(0)
# Make random data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100, 500)))
# Put some NaN values
df[np.random.random(df.shape) < .2] = np.nan
# Compute distances
d1 = compute_distances(df)
d2 = compute_distances_np(df)
print(np.allclose(d1, d2))
# True
%timeit compute_distances(df)
# 8.05 ms ± 698 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit compute_distances_np(df)
# 356 ms ± 14.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

np.random.seed(0)
# Make some random data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100, 500)))
# Put some NaN values
df[np.random.random(df.shape) < .2] = np.nan
# Compute distances
d1 = compute_distances(df)
d2 = compute_distances_np(df)
print(np.allclose(d1, d2))

%timeit compute_distances(df)
# 8.05 ms ± 698 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit compute_distances_np(df)
# 356 ms ± 14.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```